# How to highlight a table row upon hover conditionally based on table cell values with CSS and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an HTML table populated with negative and positive values. I want to query the specific values and then **upon hovering** over the table values less than 0 I want to highlight the row with a red background color and for values greater than or equal to 0 should highlight with a blue background.

My current attempt is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rows = $("#htmlTable").find('tbody').find('tr');
    $.each(rows, function(key, value){
        var rowData = $(rows[key]).find('td:eq(1)').html();
        if (rowData < 0) {
            $("tr").hover(function(){
                $(this).addClass('.table-style-1 tbody > tr:hover');
            }
        }
        else {
            $("tr").hover(function(){
                $(this).addClass('.table-style-2 tbody > tr:hover');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The CSS classes are as follows:

```
.table-style-1 tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.table-style-2 tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

My above code is correctly getting the data from the table as can been seen with a simple `console.log(rowData)` line so I am assuming that my problem is with my implementation of `addClass()` and `hover()` functions. The console isn't showing any syntax errors but the table has no highlight functionality upon hovering. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're getting a string with `rowData = $(rows[key]).find('td:eq(1)').html();`you shoud cast the value into an integer when you do a comparison, e.g.

```
if (parseInt(rowData, 10) < 0) { ...
```

Also why exactly are you adding a class like `.table-style-2 tbody > tr:hover`? You should just add the a class to the rows e.g. `negative` or `positive` (note: you need to use `$(this)` and not `$('tr')`)

```
if (parseInt(rowData, 10) < 0) {
    $(this).addClass('negative');
}
else {
    $(this).addClass('positive');
}
```

and define your css like so

```
tr.negative:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

tr.positive:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I added `parseInt()` but the table rows still are not being highlighted.

Comment: Ah it was the fact that I had `tr` rather than `this` as the calling object. Thanks for the help. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wgkf4o9j/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').on('mouseover','tr',function(event){
        var $tr = $(event.currentTarget);
        $tr.parents('table').find('td').removeClass('blue red');
        var value = parseInt($tr.find('td:eq(1)').html());      
        $tr.find('td').addClass(value < 0?'red':'blue');
    })
});
```